# Error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION - How to set the timeInterval method?

Tags: swift, timer, swift-playground

I appeal to your knowledge because I am a beginner in programming. I want to instantiate a timer via Playground. My timer is - I think - correctly configured (isValid and TimeInterval), Playground settings also too but when I want to send the message to its target I have the error message below. I searched the Apple documentation, the forums, the books but I do not get away with it. Sorry. Thanks a lot for your help.

[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLE0z.jpg)

Comment: You haven't activated the timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer calls the selector on the target that you give it. In your case, it's trying to call `AnyObject.timerFire()` which doesn't actually exist. Your implementation of `timerFire` is a global function that isn't part of a type and therefor, can't be used since Timer needs a target.

The selector needs to be a method that is exposed to ObjC, so the type needs to be a class.

Heres a simple example of what that would look like.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

class Foo {
    @objc func timerFired() {
        print("Timer Fired")
    }
}

let f = Foo()
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: f, selector: #selector(Foo.timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

print("Scheduled Timer")

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```